# How to create an empty xml in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, xml-serialization

I'm creating an empty xml file in my WP8 app like this

```
    public static bool create()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> __data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Data.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataModel>));
                using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, __data);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But I get a `System.InvalidOperationException` on the line `serializer.Serialize(stream, __data);`

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I added this line after creating the new dictionary `__data.Add("testkey", "testdatavalue");` but I still get the same exception.

Comment: Add an item for testing. It's probably not about the emptiness.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just added an edit. Is that what you meant for me to do?

Comment: Yes, now we know it's not about "empty".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

```
Dictionary<string, object> __data = ...
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataModel>));
serializer.Serialize(stream, __data);
```

So your serializer is for another Type (`DataModel`). It won't handle a `Dictionary<>`.

Comment: I posted a follow up question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634380/system-invalidoperationexception-when-reading-from-xml-in-wp8