# System.InvalidOperationException when reading from xml in WP8

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

This is a follow-up question from [How to create an empty xml in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632942/how-to-create-an-empty-xml-in-windows-phone-8).

I did this to create the xml:

```
public void create()
    {
        List<DataModel> __dataList = new List<DataModel>();

        XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Data.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataModel>));
                using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, __dataList);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to read it with this code, I get another `System.InvalidOperationException`

```
    public void read()
    {
        List<DataModel> __dataList = new List<DataModel>();
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Data.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataModel>));
                    __dataList = (List<DataModel>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string s = e.Message;
            e.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The exception message is "There is an error in XML document (2, 118)." What is wrong with my code?

**Edit**: Inner exception is "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 118."

**Edit 2**: I read the contents of the xml using `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` before deserializing and this is the return string: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfDataModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />`

This is my first time working with xml, so the issue may be a simple one but I may not realise it. Any help?

Comment: You should try to display the contents of your XML file to understand what's going on

Comment: In particular, a: what is in the xml file at (2,118), and b: what is the `.InnerException.Message`, the `.InnerException.InnerException.Message`, the `.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.Message`, etc? `XmlSerializer` actually gives **really really** detailed messages: you just need to look a few levels further into the `Exception`

Comment: @KooKiz where will the xml file be stored?

Comment: @NiiLaryea Create a StreamReader with your stream, then display the result of the `ReadToEnd` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the code below also give an error? And what is the construction of DataModel?

```
      public void create()
  {
     List<DataModel> __dataList = new List<DataModel>();

     //XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
     //xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;

     using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
     {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Data.xml", FileMode.Create))
        {
           try
           {
              XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataModel>));
              //using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
              //{
              serializer.Serialize(stream, __dataList);
              //}
           }
           catch { }
        }
     }
  }

  public void read()
  {
     List<DataModel> __dataList = new List<DataModel>();
     try
     {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
           using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Data.xml", FileMode.Open))
           {
              XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataModel>));
              __dataList = (List<DataModel>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
           }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        string s = e.Message;
        e.ToString();
     }
  }
```

And somewhere:

```
public class DataModel
{ }
```

That code above works for me.

Comment: My problem isn't with the `create()` method, it's with the `read()` method.

Comment: I think the problem is with 
XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
Do it without xmlWriter - just as I described above. I've just tried and it works. Even with OpenFile()

Comment: I took out the `XmlWriterSettings` line and the exception now reads: "There is an error in XML document (0, 0)." Inner Exception  reads: "Root element is missing."

Comment: OK - is your DataModel Class a public Class?
public class DataModel { }
And you got rid off 
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings)) ?

Comment: My DataModel class wasn't public. I can't believe that was the problem all along. Thanks a lot man